# Use Django's url template tag with special characters

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using django's url tag to move from one view to another:

```
<a href = {% url wiki_view item %}>Read more here</a>
```

For most "items" this works perfectly.  But I have an "item" with a / character: Sci-Fi/Fantasy.  In this instance, I get an error

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'wiki_view' with arguments '(u'Sci-fi/Fantasy',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

My urls.py is defined as such:

```
url(r'^wiki/page/(?P<page_title>[^/]*)/$', views.wiki_view, name = 'wiki_view'),
```

Is there a way for this to work with a "/" character in place like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `urlencode` filter as Ignacio suggests, however you are still getting a probelm as by default that filter assumes a `/` to be left alone. You can solve this (if you are using the dev version currently) by using the filter in the following way:

```
item|urlencode:""
```

This is explained in the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#urlencode).

Comment: hmm.  ok.  I'm on 1.3.0 alpha.  I'm a little hesitant to jump to the dev version because this may be needed in production.  I'll give you the answer, but if you have an alternate suggestion, it would be well appreciated.

Comment: You could [create your own filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), just copying the [code in the dev version](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L294)

Answer (score 1):

Pass the argument through [`urlencode`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode) first.

Comment: nice.  But how do I combine it with the url template tag?  I tried: <a href = {% url wiki_view item|urlencode %}>Read more here</a>, but I get the same error

Comment: @Ed. check this out https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15718 you need to do urlencode twice

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Djanog's `slugify` on anything which you are using in a URL. It replaces characters like that with URL friendly ones, and human readable alternatives.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will keep this in mind.  In this instance though, slugify removes the forward slash entirely.  When the following page is constructed, the title reads Sci-fiFantasy

Comment: Yes, probably slugify is best used with some forethought. @Ignacio's answer is therefore a better immediate fix.